# dismiss viewController by using presentingViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, ios5

I have three ViewControllers and its order is (A present B which presents C),
when I stay in the C viewController ,I have to dismiss ViewController to B viewController.

for C viewController ,its presentingViewCOntroller is B viewController

of course ,I can use

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];//self means C ViewController
```

But I was wondering I can also use the following method:

```
[self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
```

because the presentingViewController of C is B ViewController, **but** it did the same effect.
self means C ViewController while self.presentingViewController means B ViewController,but they also did the same work

The second question is I cannot use the following to dismiss two viewController in succession:

```
  [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    [self.presentingViewController.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}]; //self means C viewController
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4):

> of course ,I can use
>
> ```
> [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];//self means C ViewController
> ```

This only dismisses `C`, not `B` as you seem to want.

> But I was wondering I can also use the following method:
>
> ```
> [self.presentingViewController.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
> ```

Yes, this works. When in doubt, try it out.

> The second question is I cannot use the following to dismiss two viewController in succession:
>
> ```
> [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
>     [self.presentingViewController.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
> }]; //self means C viewController
> ```

That's not a question. Anyway, the reason it doesn't work is that after you dismiss yourself, your `presentingViewController` is `nil`. You need to store it in a temporary variable.

```
UIViewController *gp = self.presentingViewController.presentingViewController;
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    [gp dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    [self.presentingViewController.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}];
```

Of course, the two will have different animations, you'll need to decide which you prefer.

Comment: thank you for your second answer ,I'm sorry I didn't discripe the first question.I just wondering self and self.presenting represent different object,but they can do the same work

Answer (score 4):

see documentation:

> The presenting view controller is responsible for dismissing the view
>   controller it presented. **If you call this method on the presented view**
>   **controller itself, it automatically forwards the message to the**
>   **presenting view controller.**

Answer (score 0):

Please check: self.presentingViewController.presentingViewController is A viewController or not.

if not, I think you need use delegate or handler.

In my case, I used a tabbarcontroller as a rootViewController. When I used self.presentingViewController.presentingViewController, I got rootViewController (tabbarcontroller) which it have no response to presentingViewControler method.